# How to check already existing table in phpMyAdmin to avoid duplicate on adding data in new table

Tags: mysql

I am looking to create new table (table2) in phpMyAdmin and add details which is not existing in my other particular table (table1).

For example.
I have following two tables:

```
Table1
-------------
edm_id   user_id    name    email 
1        3          A       abd@mail.com
2        3          b       efg@mail.com
3        3          c       hij@mail.com

Table2
--------
edm_id   user_id    name    email 
1        3          d       fgh@mail.com
2        3          e       ijk@mail.com
```

Now, the condition is if I try to add new data in table2 (hij@mail.com) I want table2 to not allow because it already exist in table1.

Comment: how are you inserting data for 2nd table ?

Comment: You have two basically identical tables that depend on each other. The question is: why do you have two basically identical tables for this? You could make one table, add a column for the state (whatever differentiate your tables logically, e.g. add a `THIS_IS_A_GOOD_CUSTOMER`-flag and set it 1 for data that would be in table1 and 0 for data that would be in table2), and then add a unique index.

Comment: I need to create new table because my old table is untidy. So, I need to maintain a clean new table with new data which not exist in old table.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a trigger that check if data exist in table2 say error

```
CREATE DEFINER=`remote`@`%` TRIGGER `Table2_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `Table2` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

  DECLARE emailTable1 varchar(50);
  DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
  set msg = "duplicate record";

  SET emailTable1 = (
    SELECT email from table1 where email=new.email);


  if emailTable1 is not null  then
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
  end if;

END
```

Comment: I tried to execute above code but still I am getting error. Can I add trigger using add  trigger option under trigger tab in my php admin?